# wp_pagenavi() does not work on category.php. Changes URL but returns same page everytime

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, navigation

```
    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 15, 
    'cat' => $i,
    'orderby'=> 'post_date',
    'paged' => $paged );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ($loop->have_posts()): while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

 //Show loop data


endwhile;

if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi') ) { wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $loop ) ); }
wp_reset_postdata();
```

This is the code I am using and don't know why the pagination rerturns to same first page even after changing the url.

The url after pagination looks like this: https://financialnewsnepal.com/category/categoryname/page/2/

But this returns the same first page.

I am new to wordpress and I tried adding $paged query, also added an array inside wp_pagenavi() but cannot find the solutions. After going through many solutions on stackoverflow and stackexchange I cannot make it work even after trying many solutions.

Can somebody help me and guide me to make this function work in category.php where I list posts from category. I'm using a WP Page Navi Plugin for this.